# Booting from an lvm-cached volume

Tags: boot, lvm, grub, cache, uefi

I created a cache pool following [this article](http://rwmj.wordpress.com/2014/05/22/using-lvms-new-cache-feature/). The process seems to be successful.

After doing an upgrade-grub and rebooting, Grub complains that it can not find the root volume (showing a UUID). - My bad, but I can not recall if this was the id of the original volume or the cached one.

The question: *is there an article detailing the tasks to use the cached volume as the root?*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following [Debian Forum topic](https://web.archive.org/web/20160203091803/http://forums.debian.net/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=119644) and [blog post](https://web.archive.org/web/20170222123630/https://www.bradfordembedded.com/2015/03/lvmcache/) based on it has the missing information.

**Outline**

-1) Back up your LVM configuration and have a like CD ready.

0) Make sure you have a separate `/boot` partition (your cached root will only be available later). This can be a 200MB partition and can be part of the same VG as your cached root.

1) You need dm-cache in your kernel image (instead of module). check your config and make sure you have `CONFIG_DM_CACHE=y`. If it is a module (=m) you will need to recompile a kernel where this is set to **y**. It is probably a good idea to use menuconfig and set this option from there (it will make sure dm-cache's dependency chain is also `=y`).

```
    Device Drivers  --->

    Generic Driver Options  --->

--- Multiple devices driver support (RAID and LVM)
<*>   Device mapper support
<*>     Cache target (EXPERIMENTAL)
```

2) Install `thin-provisioning-tools` (will do *fsck*-like functions on the cache at boot-time).

3) Create a file in `/etc/initramfs-tools/hooks` with the following content. This will make sure the executable from step 2 and some dependencies are inside your init ramdisk image.

```
#!/bin/sh

PREREQ="lvm2"

prereqs()
{
    echo "$PREREQ"
}

case $1 in
prereqs)
    prereqs
    exit 0
    ;;
esac

if [ ! -x /usr/sbin/cache_check ]; then
    exit 0
fi

. /usr/share/initramfs-tools/hook-functions

copy_exec /usr/sbin/cache_check

manual_add_modules dm_cache dm_cache_mq
```

4) Run `update-initramfs -u -k all` to re-generate all your initrd images.

Comment: Thanks for this answer it was very helpful. It allowed me to boot a Debian Squeeze system (armel on a QNAP NAS) with an SSD cache of a RAID 1 HDD which used LVM caching. Step 1 was not necessary just having the module in the initrd was enough. Also one of the module names has changed from `dm_cache_mq` to `dm_cache_smq`.

Answer (score 2):

When using vbence's answer, also make the /etc/initramfs/hooks/ file from step 3 executable. Otherwise it won't get run by `update-initramfs`